# jQuery refresh SexyCombo Cascading Inputs

Tags: jquery, combobox, refresh

Using [sexy-combo](http://code.google.com/p/sexy-combo/) with countries, and another with cities. Whenever the user selects a country I fill the second combobox with the corresponding cities with Ajax, without doing any postback.

The problem is that the sexy combo renders the nice combobox using my html select only the first time when the page is loaded. When I update the items in the html select for the cities, it's not being refreshed so there are no values in there...

Do you know what function must I call to "refresh" the combobox, just like it would be refreshed when I do a postback?

Any hint is very welcomed! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you put together a demo page? Ideally on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), but failing that a link to a live page on your own site would be, at the least, helpful so that we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I was missing is calling this function:

```
$.sexyCombo.changeOptions($('#cities')[0]);
```

This forces the sexy combobox of the cities to be rendered after I changed the options of the html select control to which is binded using javascript.

@Sarzniak and @Majid: thank you very much for your answers, but it was not quite what I was looking for, maybe I haven't made myself clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the 'live' binding function from jQuery.
When you refresh your item then the events aren't binded any more to your objects.

example

```
$("myItem").live("click",function(){ codeHere });
```

this also binds the 'click' event to your ajax-created items.

Answer (score 0):

If your old code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sexify').sexify({options});
  $('select[name="countries"]').change(function() {
    var selected_country = $(this).val();
    $('select[name="cities"]').load('cities.php?country=' + selected_country);
  });
});
```

then all you need is add a function as `.load`'s callback like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sexify').sexify({options});
  $('select[name="countries"]').change(function() {
    var selected_country = $(this).val();
    $('select[name="cities"]').load('cities.php?country=' + selected_country, function() {
      $(this).sexify({options});
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another method in the script, e.g. below "changeOptions":

```
custom_update: function($select) {
    $select = $($select);
    $select.each(function() {
        if ("SELECT" != this.tagName.toUpperCase()) {
            return; 
        }

        var my_text = $("#"+ this.id + " option:selected").text();
        var my_val = $("#"+ this.id + " option:selected").val();
        var $this = $(this);
        var $wrapper  = $this.parent();
        var $input = $wrapper.find("input[type='text']");
        var $listWrapper = $wrapper.find("ul").parent();

        $listWrapper.removeClass("visible").
        addClass("invisible");
        $wrapper.css("zIndex", "0");
        $listWrapper.css("zIndex", "99999");            

        //$input.val("");
        $wrapper.data("sc:optionsChanged", "yes");
        var $selectbox = $this;
        $selectbox.parent().find("input[type='text']").val($selectbox.find("option:eq(" + my_val + ")").text());
        $selectbox.parent().data("sc:lastEvent", "click");
        $selectbox.find("option:eq(" + my_val + ")").attr('selected','selected');
    });
},
```

And call it like:

```
$.sexyCombo.custom_update($("#myselectlist"));
```